# How to convert a Hashtable to a Thread in c#?

Tags: c#, vb.net, performance, asp.net-core, refactoring

i'm refactoring some old code, and i stumbled upon something weird, and i don't know exactly how it works and neither why it works(average junior dev experience), Basically there is a code in VBNET that i want to convert to c#, and this code does the following, it Converts a Hashtable to a Thread, i hope i've been clear, i'm not very familiar with vb.net, ]

```
Dim trdAux As Thread = CType(trdProgramHash(shtCodigoPrograma), Thread)
```

Comment: Could you edit the question and include the definitions of the `trdProgramHash` and the `shtCodigoPrograma`?

Comment: as i mentioned, trdprogramHash is a hashtable, and i want to convert it to a tread, there is no reason for further  explanation than that

Comment: The question does not really make any sense to me. A hash table is a data structure for storing some type of data. A thread is OS/Cpu construct for running some piece of code. They are completely different things. It is like asking how to convert an orange to an airplane. So the code probably does something different, but we are in no position to tell you what without more code examples.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

**Disclaimer: I can't tell you why the VB code works but this would be the C# equivalent:**

Have you tried casting it as a Thread?

Something like that:

```
Thread trdAux = (Thread)trdProgramHash(shtCodigoPrograma);
```

Comment: is this an answer or q question? Anyway I doubt that's gonna work, as there's no connection between a hastbale and a thread.

Comment: I have not tried it out tbh, it was just the thing that came to my mind first. @MakePeaceGreatAgain

Comment: @MakePeaceGreatAgain tbh it's more or less exactly what the vb code does.

Comment: which makes me wonder how on earth that could solve OPs problem.

Comment: damd you are probably right I have misread the question. I'll add a disclaimer to my answer as OP seems to have accepted it anyways.